# Printing A Bill

Tags: python-3.x

I need the print statement to print each item inputted to the list. So, if I buy 1 apple for 1.49 and 1 milk for 3.99 . The output should display

- "1 Apple @ 1.49 ea 1.49"
- "1 milk @ 3.99 ea 3.99
- "Grand total: $5.48

currently displaying:

- "1 milk @ 3.99"
- "1 milk @ 3.99"
- "Grand total: $5.48"

Here is my code:
'''

```
    grocery_item = {}
    grocery_history = []

'''    
    stop = 'c'

    while stop == 'c':

      item_name = input("Item name:\n")
      quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")   
      cost = input("Price per item:\n")


      grocery_item['name'] = item_name   
      grocery_item['number'] = quantity 
      grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)

      grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

      stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\n Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")


      grand_total = 0


    for items in range(0, len(grocery_history)):


        item_total = int(grocery_history[items].get('number')) * float(grocery_history[items].get('price'))

        grand_total = grand_total + float(item_total)

    print(str(grocery_history[items]['number']) + ' ' + str(grocery_history[items]['name']) + ' @ $' + str(grocery_history[items]['price']) + ' ea $' + str('%.2f' % item_total))

    item_total = 0
    print(str('Grand total: $%.2f' % grand_total))
```

Comment: move the print statement inside the for loop

Comment: @JBernardo it is in the for loop on my scripting program, it just repeats the last item sequence input instead of each separate item input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `grocery_item = {}` inside the while loop.

Then move the `print(str(grocery_history[items]['number']) + ' ' + str(grocery_history[items]['name']) + ' @ $' + str(grocery_history[items]['price']) + ' ea $' + str('%.2f' % item_total))`
 line inside the for loop

The full code should be like this,

```
grocery_history = []
stop = 'c'

while stop == 'c':
  grocery_item = {}
  item_name = input("Item name:\n")
  quantity = input("Quantity purchased:\n")   
  cost = input("Price per item:\n")


  grocery_item['name'] = item_name   
  grocery_item['number'] = quantity 
  grocery_item['price'] = float(cost)

  grocery_history.append(grocery_item)

  stop = input("Would you like to enter another item?\n Type 'c' for continue or 'q' to quit:\n")


  grand_total = 0


for items in range(0, len(grocery_history)):


    item_total = int(grocery_history[items].get('number')) * float(grocery_history[items].get('price'))

    grand_total = grand_total + float(item_total)

    print(str(grocery_history[items]['number']) + ' ' + str(grocery_history[items]['name']) + ' @ $' + str(grocery_history[items]['price']) + ' ea $' + str('%.2f' % item_total))

item_total = 0
print(str('Grand total: $%.2f' % grand_total))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain to a new person in scripting, why moving it inside the while loop  made a difference?

Comment: In the given code, you are initializing the grocery_item dictionary outside the while loop and keep updating it every time you have a new item in the bill. This force to update the values of the same dictionary and keep pushing it to the list.
By moving it inside the while loop, you can create a new local dictionary per each item and push it to the list. Hence, you are not updating the previous values.